# mod_jk to forward to tomcat installed on other server?

Tags: tomcat, apache-2.2, mod-jk

Is it possible to forward the request from IBM HTTP server installed on solaris machine to Tomcat installed on windows machine using mod_jk?

IHS is installed on solaris and I have attached mod_jk connector in it.
tomcat is installed on windows server 2008 and listens to ajp13 port 8009 as

my worker file in solaris as,

```
worker.list=testWorker
worker.testWorker.port=8009
worker.testWorker.host=<IP address of windows machine>
worker.testWorker.type=ajp13
```

httpd.conf file is,

```
LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so

JkWorkersFile conf/workers.properties
JkLogFile logs/mod_jk.log
JkLogLevel debug
JkMount /* ajp13
```

when i send a request to IHS it does not redirect to tomcat. I get following error in mod_jk log,

> [Wed Jun 29 06:35:53 2011] 
>   [jk_uri_worker_map.c (445)]: Into
>   jk_uri_worker_map_t::map_uri_to_worker
>   [Wed Jun 29 06:35:53 2011] 
>   [jk_uri_worker_map.c (459)]:
>   Attempting to map URI
>   '/inquiry/brand/ncr' [Wed Jun 29
>   06:35:53 2011]  [jk_uri_worker_map.c
>   (483)]:
>   jk_uri_worker_map_t::map_uri_to_worker,
>   Found a context match ajp13 -> / [Wed
>   Jun 29 06:35:53 2011]  [mod_jk.c
>   (1689)]: Into handler r->proxyreq=0
>   r->handler=jakarta-servlet
>   r->notes=1714776 worker=ajp13 [Wed Jun
>   29 06:35:53 2011]  [jk_worker.c (90)]:
>   Into wc_get_worker_for_name ajp13 [Wed
>   Jun 29 06:35:53 2011]  [jk_worker.c
>   (94)]: wc_get_worker_for_name, done
>   did not find a worker

Why it is not able to find the worker? 
I search the internet but everywhere host is set to localhost in workers file, but it is separate physical machine in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JkMount /* ajp13
```

should be changed into

```
JkMount /* ajp13 testWorker
```

in `httpd.conf`

Comment: you are right.. I figured that out after posting but can replay upto 8 hours to my post :(